# Jira plugin showing JWT error how to resolve it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jira, jira-plugin

I am new to Jira and I had created one spring-boot Jira Add-on application and while uploading it to Jira cloud it is showing me the below error:

```
2022-07-07 11:35:56.853 DEBUG 186440 --- [nio-8986-exec-4] 
c.a.c.s.i.a.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter  : Retrieved JWT from request
2022-07-07 11:35:56.882 DEBUG 186440 --- [nio-8986-exec-4] c.a.c.s.i.a.j.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Parsed JWT: {"aud":"https:\/\/22ee-453-8-229-155.eu.ngrok.io","sub":"62c31d1b7273faf658f05a12","qsh":"4a2e1de8ca74e6cafe8862d332fa3ac7a8e51e692bc6d798ea4dfedc14948bf4","iss":"4c9d214a-0e94-31be-b935-0009eef5ae41","context":{},"exp":1657191055,"iat":1657190155}
2022-07-07 11:35:56.914 DEBUG 186440 --- [nio-8986-exec-4] c.a.c.s.i.a.j.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Could not find an installed host for the provided client key: 4c9d214a-0e94-31be-b935-0009eef5ae41
2022-07-07 11:35:56.929  WARN 186440 --- [nio-8986-exec-4] c.a.c.s.i.a.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter  : Failed to authenticate request
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_322]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_322]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_322]

2022-07-07 11:35:56.929  WARN 186440 --- [nio-8986-exec-4] c.a.c.s.i.a.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter  : Received JWT authentication from unknown host (4c9d214a-0e94-31be-b935-0009eef5ae41), but allowing anyway
2022-07-07 11:35:56.929 DEBUG 186440 --- [nio-8986-exec-4] .s.i.l.LifecycleControllerHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.atlassian.connect.spring.internal.lifecycle.LifecycleController#installed(LifecycleEvent, AtlassianHostUser)
2022-07-07 11:35:57.073  INFO 186440 --- [         task-1] c.a.c.s.i.lifecycle.LifecycleController  : Saved installation for host https://KoK345.atlassian.net (4c9d214a-0e94-31be-b935-0009eef5ae41)
```

and my connect.json file is as below:

```
{
"key": "atlassian-connect-spring-boot-sample-basic",
  "baseUrl": "https://22ee-453-8-229-155.eu.ngrok.io",
  "name": "Atlassian Connect Spring Boot Basic Sample",
  "authentication": {
    "type": "jwt"
  },
  "apiMigrations": {
    "signed-install": true
  },
  "lifecycle": {
    "installed": "/installed",
    "uninstalled": "/uninstalled"
  }, "modules": {
  "generalPages": [
    {
      "key": "atlaskit-page-jira",
      "location": "system.top.navigation.bar",
      "name": {
        "value": "App"
      },
      "url": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Please can anyone help me why this is happening what wrong am I doing?

Comment: the clue is within this line: Unsupported JWS algorithm RS256, must be HS256, HS384 or HS512

Comment: Yes @Stultuske but I am selecting any JWT algorithm in connect.json I am just passing type = jwt, it is by Default selected Jira only.